# Ionic Native Storage is not persisting after rebuilding app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-nativestorage

I am using ionic 3 native storage and store a value like this:

```
this.storage.set('myValue', this.value);
```

Then I rebuild the app and try to get that value and it returns null:

```
this.storage.get('myValue').then(value => {
console.log('My value: ' + value);
})
```

The result is: My value: null

Not sure why its doing this isn't storage suppose to store it in the database so it should not matter if I rebuild the app or not?

Comment: by rebuild you just mean reuploading to phone...not uninstalling right?

Comment: @ewizard yes thats correct not uninstalling

Comment: can you show where you are using the `.set` in your code? what is around it? same with `.get`. and yah rebuilding shouldnt matter...once its stored its stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [**SQLite plugin**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/#usage).

> When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using
>   SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based
>   databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage
>   and IndexedDB, such as the OS deciding to clear out such data in low
>   disk-space situations.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ;

```
this.storage.get('myValue').then((data) => {
console.log('My Value : ' + data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Why should OP try this? What does it do? How is it different? How does it solve the problem? (Code only answers are not very useful)